# jquery select text with tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to select text inside < P> with other tag like < b>,< i>
for e.g.

```
<td rowspan="2" width="28%" valign="top" > 
<p>Hello <b> John</b>< p>
</td>
```

here in above example, is it possible to fetch  "Hello < b> John" with jquery selector

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to get html content. Try this:

```
$(function() {
  alert($("p").html()); 
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kwxv5soh/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$('p').html();
```

will be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('p').html();
```

will get you

```
Hello <b> John</b>
```